# Connecting a Java application to an SQL database with Eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, connection, sqlexception

I know this has been asked before but I really can't get this to work and as far as I can see I've followed all the steps.

I'm using Eclipse.

So I downloaded the Microsoft SQL Driver sqljdbc v4.0. 
I created a new project and class. I edited the build path by adding the .jar file to the libraries.

I typed the following code:

```
package com.test.sql;
import java.sql.*;
public class Connect
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    Connection con = null;
    String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=AnotherTestDB;";
    try
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I got the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=AnotherTestDB;
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.sql.Connect.main(Connect.java:11)
```

A bit more research and I was told put it in the java /lib/ext and reference it from there.

Nothing changed.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.

I had both the sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc.jar referenced. The version of Java I am using requires that I use sqljdbc4.jar but it was being overwritten by sqljdbc.jar so I removed it.

I also changed my code to this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://nameMyLaptop//SQLEXPRESS";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    }

//Insert catches
}
```

Apparently I didn't have to change the code but its not giving me that error now. I'm getting a new one but that's unrelated to my question.

Thanks for your time and responses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **SQL JDBC Driver** in your project libraries. download [`jtds.jar`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/) and add to your libraries. And follow the code below.

```
   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

   Connection conn=null;

   String url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://YourServerIp:1433/dbName";
   String username="sa";
   String password="****";
   String driver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver.
   Class.forName(driver);
    // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.
   conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,
                                password);

}
```

Here you have to follow two steps......

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to register the driver before accessing to it:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
String DRIVER = “oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver”;
String DBURL = “jdbc:oracle:thin:@jiplc0.si.ehu.es:1512:Erreala”; 
String UID = “USERNAME”;
String PWD = “PASSWORD”;

￼Driver kontrolatzailea = (Driver) (Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance()); 
DriverManager.registerDriver(kontrolatzailea);
DefaultContext test = new DefaultContext(DBURL, UID, PWD, false); 
DefaultContext.setDefaultContext(test);
```